# Centos7 extras and rhel7 extras missing packages issue

Tags: centos, redhat, yum, centos7, rhel7

I asked this on stack overflow and realised it is probably more appropriate to ask here.

I am merging ansible into our internal RHN satellite. I have a fully updated RHEL 7 base repo, extras, supplementary, optional, and RHN tools from Red Hat. I have also merged selected packages into a internal epel repo when we need them. This for example is where ansible is going to live.

In centos7:

```
python-crypto x86_64 2.6.1-1.el7.centos  extras  470 k
python-ecdsa  noarch 0.11-3.el7.centos   extras  69 k
```

These 2 packages are dependencies for ansible and are in the extras repo for centos7. They are however missing from Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 extras.

I was always under the impression that there would not be packages officially released from Centos that would not also be officially released from Red Hat.

My issue is that I don't want to put this in my epel repo cause it's not epel. This is the first time that I have ever experienced that there are packages offered by centos that are not a part of the corresponding Red Hat distribution. Version differences I can understand, but a missing package seems odd to me.

Is this an error? Should this not happen?

Comment: These are usually in the RHEL optional channel. Are you quite certain you have that?

Comment: In the past I noticed that what Red Hat offers as [add-ons](https://www.redhat.com/apps/store/add-ons/) appears in the CentOS default enabled [repo's](https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/General#head-92ba307b036080a16dbffa44486cde25c081fcca)

Comment: @MichaelHampton On a stock Centos7 box yum lists both packages as coming from 

`Repo        : extras/7/x86_64`

I have check both optional and extras Red Hat Channels on my satellite and they are up to date with Red Hat.  These packages are not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those packages appear to be from the [extras](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories) repo:

> **CentOS Extras** - In CentOS 5 and 6, packages that provide additional functionality to CentOS without breaking upstream compatibility or updating base components, but are not tested by upstream or available in the upstream product. **In CentOS 7 this is an upstream repository, as well as additional CentOS packages.** The CentOS development team have tested every item in this repository and they all work with CentOS. This repository is shipped with CentOS and is **enabled by default**

(*emphasis mine*)

So although the extras channel is present in RHEL 7, the CentOS 7 extras repository contains additional packages.

Comment: ok so I have simply misunderstood the change in CentOS7 in that the extras repo can contain additional packages from CentOS.  It is normal in 7 that Rhel7-extras and CentOS7-extras may have some differences between the packages offered.  Thank you for the answer.